# Cannot accurately parse this JSON in script?

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc, razor

```
var var1 = JSON.parse('[{"ItemId":1, "ItemName":"item 1\"", "Unit":"Nos","Remarks":null, "ConsumedQuantity":1.00},
        {"ItemId":1253, "ItemName":"item 2", "Unit":"Nos", "Remarks":null, "ConsumedQuantity":1.00}]');

var1.forEach(function (e) {
    Object.keys(e).forEach(function (key) {
        if (e[key] == id) {
           //doing some stuff here
        }
    });
});
```

This code works perfectly when the value in the JSON doesn't contain double quotes. This JSON is produced from a list of Model in MVC. 
I use `@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.materialDetails))` to convert the list to JSON. When there is a double quote, then it doesn't enter into the `forEach`.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: should be two \\ to escape it when it is in a string `"ItemName":"item 1\\""`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.materialDetails))` should return valid JSON data so you don't need to add ticks around it or `JSON.parse` it.

If you change

```
var var1 = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.materialDetails))');
```

to:

```
var var1 = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.materialDetails));
```

it might work

Comment: @Sphinxxx Nice! :)

Comment: Perfect ! Thanks :)